# Add Andorid library to Jetpack Compose project, build failed with "Uninitialized.application.id" in Merged Manifest

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I created a new compose project with "Empty Compose Activity" on Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1; then added a new Android library to the project. When I try to build the project, it says "Build: failed"

[image]

Comment: I see a strange package name in your library's manifest file. When adding the android library did you specify a package name for it?

Comment: Why are you adding that package attribute to your manifest? Well, if you are not, then there is a specification that you need to add in your app level build. Something like `plugin <name>` where name is the one from the library to be added

Comment: I was having merge issue issue while migrating current project to use Jetpack compose.  So I create a new compose project, Test1Compose, with an Android library, myLib to see if I can reproduce the same issue.  I didn't make change to the manifest files, they were created the new project with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found and fixed the issue after using command: ./gradlew build

This version (1.0.0) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.20 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

It has nothing to do with “Uninitialized.application.id” in Merged Manifest